# split url to classname and filename url

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

in my project , i need to use uri to locate resouce ,the resouce could be a jpeg ,bmp , png,txt,xml,or any file type,but there's an exception. when i need to locate a class in a swf file. i use classname@filename format

the client needs to exam whether it's a general url or a flash url.

a general url would be like this

.../filename?...

a specific flash class url

.../classname@filename?...

needs turn into [.../filename?...,classname]

since the url was not only for download ,but also for key and hash. so the split function got to be very efficient.  please tell me the best way you know to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression such as `([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)@` in conjunction with `String.match()` or `String.replace()`. However, a simple `String.indexOf('@')` should be used to test if you are actually dealing with a URI containing a class name.

If performance is a concern, look at this page about [regular expressions optimization](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6711168a01275489830e-8000.html) from Adobe.